# how to exit a function using the ternary operator

Tags: javascript, function, dom, exit, conditional-operator

I have this incompleted code right here

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click', function() {
    scores[activePlayer] += roundScore
    document.querySelector("#score-" + activePlayer).textContent = scores[activePlayer]
    //checking if the player won the game
    scores[activePlayer] === 20? /*exit the function*/ :  /*move to the next player*/ nextPlayer()
})
```

I tried 'return' but it has an error.

Comment: `if(scores[activePlayer] !== 20) nextPlayer();`

Comment: The ternary operator is often useful for short statements. But please, don't just use it for the sake of using it. If you don't want to do anything when the condition passes, the ternary operator does not have its place here

Comment: If you don't need a result value, don't use a ternary operator expression.

Comment: But just for fun a short form would be `scores[activePlayer] === 20 || nextPlayer()`.

Comment: @blex oh , thanks for clearing this up for me.

Comment: @iY1NQ, i've never thought of that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is unnecessary for control-flow, and more useful if you're trying to return a value from the operator. You should consider simplifying it to a simple `if` statement.

```
if (scores[activePlayer] !== 20)
    nextPlayer();
```

and just let the function exit naturally if false.

Comment: oh, thanks, the thing is i was just following a course and the insturctor used the if else statement, but i thought i can do it in another way,